How to count the number of read/write units being used on KV?
The free plan of Deno Deploy gives me 450,000 read units and 300,000 write units per month. One read unit is equivalent to 4 KiB of read. If you read a 2 KiB record this is 1 read unit. If you read 4.1 KiB record then it's 2 read units. If you use the list function and read 10 records and their total size is 3 KiB, then this is 1 read unit in total.
As I'm still building the app I think most of my activity should be set, not get. Yet I have used all the read quota for this month, while only used 479 write units. I think something is wrong here.
My idea to investigate this better is to replace kv.get operation with my custom kvGet function. Here is my test script:
import sizeof from "npm:object-sizeof";

const kv = await Deno.openKv()

const dummyData = 'This dummy data should have 10240 characters, exactly equal to 10 KiB. Each request should consume 3 read units and 10 write units. For full data see https://gist.github.com/aal89/4b77a7e483186061487bf46113a4c9a0'

let readUnitTotal = 0
let writeUnitTotal = 0
const css = "color: blue; font-style: bold; border: solid blue";
await kvGet(['dummy'])
await kvSet(['dummy'], dummyData )

console.log("\nResult")
const result = `Data size: ${sizeof(dummyData)}\nRead: ${readUnitTotal}\nWrite: ${writeUnitTotal}`
console.log(result)
Deno.serve((req: Request) => new Response(result));

function increaseReadUnit(data: any) {
  const KiB = sizeof(data) / 1024;
  const readUnits = Math.ceil(KiB / 4);
  readUnitTotal += readUnits;
  console.log(`Read units: %c${readUnits}`, css);
}

function increaseWriteUnit(data: any) {
  const KiB = sizeof(data) / 1024;
  const writeUnit = Math.ceil(KiB);
  writeUnitTotal += writeUnit;
  console.log(`Write units: %c${writeUnit}`, css);
}

export async function kvGet(key: Deno.KvKey) {
  const result = await kv.get(key);
  increaseReadUnit(result);
  return result;
}

export async function kvList(prefix: Deno.KvListSelector) {
  const result = await Array.fromAsync(kv.list(prefix));
  increaseReadUnit(result);
  return result;
}

export async function kvSet(key: Deno.KvKey, value: any) {
  await kv.set(key, value);
  increaseWriteUnit(value);
}

Here is the result in Deno Deploy analytics graph:



Time
Request Count
Transferred Bytes (MiB)
KV Read Unit
KV Write Unit
Note




00:41
19
14.9
21
220
Start from here


00:42




Make 1st request


00:47
21
15.9
25
230



00:48




Make 2nd request


00:59
22
16.6
25
230




The request count column is correct. However I don't get why transferred bytes each time is 0.7 to 1 MiB, while it should be 20 KiB? And why does the 1st request increase the read and write unit, but not the 2nd request?
